# ValidationRules In C# WPF MVVM issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have Login screen, when user enters a wrong credentials, on same UI some message should display, may be just below the username and password. Note that after button click

My present code: when user enters correct credentials it will enter into some if condition for next screen, if wrong credentials  then control enters into else condition from else condition I should show some Error on same UI.
Note: I am following MVVM and I don’t want to use MesssageBox.show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have Label below to the button or where ever you want to display the error, bind the string property which is empty initially and when ever there is error Set the error message to the property that is bound to the Label, or even you can hide and show the label which displays the error